# How to Include a New FXML from within Scene Builder

Tags: user-interface, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have this code example I found online which shows an fxml document open and one of its nodes is another fxml document. It's called 'FXML VBox'. I can see how to write the fxml code directly to include another fxml file. But I can't find any way to do it inside scene builder. There is File->Include->FXML but that only lets you include an Existing file (and it doesnt work anyways for some reason).

Does anyone know how to create a new fxml file as a node rather than using one of the drop down options?

[image]

Comment: (thanks for the edit, I wasn't able to post directly because not enough reputation)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look to this:

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/19889882/javafx-tabpane-one-controller-for-each-tab

And if you want to use it in the Scene Builder you should use "File->Import->FXML" not "File->Include->FXML"

Comment: Thats the code way to do it. I'm looking for Scene Builder way. But it's probably not possible...