# JavaFx TabPane : One controller per Tab

Tags: javafx, tabs, controller

I'm new with javafx and i'm trying to have one controller per tab in a tabpane.
I found this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19889980/393984 which lead me to do this :

**Main.fxml**

```
<TabPane fx:controller="sample.Controller" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null">
  <tabs>
    <Tab text="Configuration">
      <content>
        <fx:include fx:id="mConfigTabPage" source="configTab.fxml"/>
      </content>
    </Tab>
    <Tab text="TODO">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      </content>
    </Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

**configTab.fxml**

```
<Pane fx:controller="sample.ConfigController" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="23.0" layoutY="22.0" text="API Key :" />
      <TextField layoutX="95.0" layoutY="18.0" fx:id="mAPIKey" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

**Controller.java**

```
public class Controller {
    private Stage mStage;

    @FXML
    private ConfigController mConfigTabPage;

    public void Controller(){}

    public void setStage(Stage stage)
    {
        mStage = stage;
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("CONTROLLER");
    }
}
```

**ConfigController.java**

```
public class ConfigController {
    public void ConfigController(){}

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("CONFIG CONTROLLER");
    }
}
```

My program is launching if i remove

```
@FXML
private ConfigController mConfigTabPage;
```

in the main controller.

But as soon as i add it i have the following exception :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
>   sample.ConfigController field sample.Controller.mConfigTabPage to
>   javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane

So i'm guessing that javafx trying to cast my controller into an AnchorPane and that causing the problem.

What should i do to be able to have a reference of each pane's controllers in my main controller ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFx Nested Controllers (FXML <include>)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543487/javafx-nested-controllers-fxml-include)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the *controller* of something with `fx:id="something"` append the suffix `Controller` to your Java member field. So you have to use:

```
@FXML
private ConfigController mConfigTabPageController;
```

See [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers).