# Can I write code for different Javafx Tabs in different classes

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a bus ticketing system and I have designed the GUI with JavaFX.

I have used a lot of tabs for different entities designed through scene builder.

My question is: can I make different controller class for each tab having same FXML file? I'm finding that if I code for all the tabs in same controller class it is really getting messy.

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38095562/1531971 (If not, you need to tell us why, by showing your [mcve].)

Comment: You should make each unique `Tab`'s content be its own FXML file and `fx:include` them into the `TabPane`. That way each `Tab` will have its own controller.