# Using two controller classes for the same fxml file

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx

Until now I've been always setting up the controller from the `fxml` file like this in the root element:

```
fx:controller = "control.MainController"
```

I have a **window with 2 tabs**, each of them full of buttons, tables and other elements... To keep my project in order and easy to read/maintain I would like to separate the controller code in `FirstTabController` and `SecondTabController`. How to do it?

Can I use **two different files as controller classes of the same `fxml` file**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX TabPane - One controller for each tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889882/javafx-tabpane-one-controller-for-each-tab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [JavaFX TabPane - One controller for each tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889882/javafx-tabpane-one-controller-for-each-tab) - you should use `fx:include` tag.

Main.java (assuming all the files are in the `sample` package)

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

  public void start(Stage stage) {
    Parent root = null;

    try {
      root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
    stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
  }
}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>

<TabPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <Tab text="Tab 1">
        <content>
            <fx:include source="tab1.fxml"/>
        </content>
    </Tab>
    <Tab text="Tab 2">
        <content>
            <fx:include source="tab2.fxml"/>
        </content>
    </Tab>
</TabPane>
```

tab1.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="sample.TabOneController">
    <Label text="Tab 1"/>
</StackPane>
```

tab2.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="sample.TabTwoController">
    <Label text="Tab 2"/>
</StackPane>
```

FXML files added with the `fx:include` tag are separate files which can have separate controllers.

Comment: Hello, this solution does not work and throws an exception at the main class on line 16